# Existe método que mostre o primeiro dia da semana corrente?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Algo como:

```
DateTime.Now.StartWeek();
```

E diga que é o domingo anterior a essa data.

Tem algum método pronto para isso? Se não tem, como resolver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não tem, mas é fácil fazer. Na verdade, nem todos os casos o domingo é o primeiro dia da semana, então vou permitir escolher.

```
using System;
using static System.Console;

WriteLine(DateTime.Now.StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday));
WriteLine(DateTime.Now.StartOfWeek());

public static class DateTimeExtensions {
    public static DateTime StartOfWeek(this DateTime dt, DayOfWeek startOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday) => dt.AddDays(-(7 + (dt.DayOfWeek - startOfWeek)) % 7).Date;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/qyKwCI). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/w5uKyE). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/FirstDayThisWeek.cs).